# In django application dynamic images are missing after restarting server

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django app I create a bunch of models at runtime dynamically. The models are created fine and they are registered properly. However, when I restart the server that my app is running on, the  images are missing but the text are displaying only images are missing.

Comment: Can you share some example code to show how you create the models, restart the server and display images?

Comment: It's important to include a minimal reproducible example (if you can) when asking a question so that others can better understand your problem. It also helps others help you easier and also increases the likely hood that you get helpful answers. I included a link that explains "minimal reproducible examples"

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example